# Integrating a triangle in a 2d plane, bound by $y=4x, x=1$ and $y=0$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I would like to complete the surface integral $\int\int x^2y^2dxdy$ bound by the triangle $y=4x$,  $y=0$,
$x=1$ integrating over y first. I can do the integral itself, however, I'm unsure of what limits to choose at each stage

Answer (score 0):

If you invert the integral using the Frobenius Theorem you trivially get
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{4x} x^2y^2dydx$$

Comment: thank you. and what if you integrate over x first?

Comment: When $x\in(0,1), y\in $what? And when $y=4x, x=$what?